# Real eigenspaces of a matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ are the union of straight lines trajectories and the fixed point $y\equiv 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to show that real eigenspaces of a matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ are the union of straight lines trajectories and the fixed point $y\equiv 0$. I'm studying this in the field of systems of linear differential equations.

If we have the equation
\begin{equation}
y'(t)=Ay(t)+g(t)
\end{equation}

and consider

\begin{equation}
y'(t)=Ay(t)
\end{equation}

the solution to the homogeneous system involves scalar multiples of the eigenvectors of the matrix $A$.
Moreover, the general solutions to this homogeneous system involves linearly independent eigenvectors (which can be generalized eigenvectors). Of course, here we have two straight lines in the phase plane corresponding to this solution, which isn't the same line since those eigenvectors are linearly independent.

If we think about an eigenspace as $E(A,\lambda)=\{\alpha v_\lambda:\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$ since if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then there exist $v_\lambda\neq\vec{0}$ such that $Av_\lambda=\lambda v_\lambda$ and if we multiply by $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ both sides, $\alpha (Av_\lambda)=A(\alpha v_\lambda)=\alpha\lambda v_\lambda\in E(A,\lambda)$. Is is trivial that $y\equiv 0$ is in any eigenspace.

However, i'm not sure if I'm done. Do I have to take any consideration with the non-homogeneous part of the system? I think I don't because eigenspaces of the matrix are not related to $g(t)$, but I'm not completely sure I have to prove something else. Any hint with this pseudo-proof?